# F# operator overloading riddle

Tags: f#, operator-overloading

In F# operator overloading seems powerful but also tricky to get right.
I have following class:

```
 type Value<'T> = 
    with
        static member inline  (+) (a : Value<'U>, b: Value<'U>) : Value<'U> = 
           do stuff
```

If i define another overload for + with :

```
static member inline  (+) (a : Value<'U>, b: 'U) : Value<'U> = 
           do stuff
```

It works. But if i want a symmetric operator:

```
static member inline  (+) (b: 'U, a : Value<'U>) : Value<'U> = 
           do stuff
```

The compiler complains:

```
let a = Value<int>(2);
let b = a + 3 // ok
let c = 3 + a //<-- error here
```

**Error 3 Type inference problem too complicated (maximum iteration depth reached). Consider adding further type annotations**

Is there a way around this and stay generic?

I am using F# 3.1

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The compiler never has a choice: When you apply the `(+)` operator, you either give it something of type `int` or something of type `Value<'U>`. Something of type `int` cannot be considered of type `Value<'U>`, and vice versa.

Let's try this in the interpreter. I made the two implementations output A and B so we can tell which is being called:

```
> type Value<'T> = 
-       { a : 'T  }
-     with
-         static member inline (+) (a : Value<'U>, b: Value<'U>) : Value<'U> = 
-            printfn "A"; a
-         static member inline (+) (a : Value<'U>, b: int) : Value<'U> = 
-            printfn "B"; a
- ;;

type Value<'T> =
  {a: 'T;}
  with
    static member ( + ) : a:Value<'U> * b:Value<'U> -> Value<'U>
    static member ( + ) : a:Value<'U> * b:int -> Value<'U>
  end
```

Now we have a type. Let's make a value of it.

```
> let t = { a = "foo" };;

val t : Value<string> = {a = "foo";}
```

We can now try the overloads. First `int`:

```
> t + 4;;
B
val it : Value<string> = {a = "foo";}
```

Ok. Now `Value<string>`:

```
> t + t;;
A
val it : Value<string> = {a = "foo";}
```

Comment: Actually i will rephrase the question, because i asked it wrong. Thank for answering

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22401010/f-operator-overloading-riddle-2), my preferred solution would be to use a base class for some overloads:

```
type BaseValue<'T>(v : 'T) =
    member x.V = v

type Value<'T>(v : 'T) =
    inherit BaseValue<'T>(v : 'T)
    static member inline  (+) (a : Value<_>, b: Value<_>) = Value(b.V+a.V)

type BaseValue with
    static member inline  (+) (a: BaseValue<_>, b) = Value(b+a.V)
    static member inline  (+) (b, a: BaseValue<_>) = Value(b+a.V)


// test
let v = Value(2)
let a = v + v
let b = v + 3
let c = 3 + v
let d = Value(Value 7) + Value(Value 10)
let e = 5 + 7
```

Comment: Epic. This code locks down IntelliSense in VS2015 for quite a while. I got it down for about two minutes just by adding some of those values and then editing the line where `v` is defined.

Comment: @Vandroiy I'm not surprised, most likely related to this [known bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/343)

Answer (score 0):

Note that this problem disappears if you use the same type argument on your members as you do on the class itself:

```
type Value<'t when 't : (static member (+) : 't * 't -> 't)> = V of 't with
    static member inline (+)(V(x:'t), V(y:'t)) : Value<'t> = V(x+y)
    static member inline (+)(V(x:'t), y:'t)    : Value<'t> = V(x+y)
    static member inline (+)(x:'t,    V(y:'t)) : Value<'t> = V(x+y)
```

This means that you can't create instances of type `Value<obj>` any more, but might meet your needs.

Comment: Strangely enough, with a record type, it works even without annotations – and allows instantiation with types like `obj`. Looks like some inconsistent compiler behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This operator definition is not sensible, though interestingly, neither is the compiler's reaction.

First of all, think about the intended return type of adding two `Value<_>` objects. It could be `Value<Value<_>>`! Language semantics aside, there is no reason to assume that a fully generic type like this shouldn't be nested within itself. **This `+` operator is ill-defined.** Type inference will always fail on the overload that adds two `Value<_>` instances, as the compiler will be unable to resolve the ambiguity.

But the more fundamental question is: what does this operator even mean? Add values and maybe wrap them in an extra type? Those are two entirely different operations; I don't see the merit of combining them, let alone implicitly and in a possibly ambiguous manner. It might save a lot of hassle to only define addition for two `Value` instances and construct them explicitly where needed.

---

That aside, it looks like the compiler is quite unintuitive in this case. Someone who knows the F# specification in detail may be able to tell whether it's a bug or inconsistent design, but look at how similar variants behave:

```
type Value<'T> =
    { Raw : 'T }

    static member inline (+) (v, w) = { Raw = v.Raw + w.Raw }
    static member inline (+) (v, a) = { Raw = v.Raw + a }
    static member inline (+) (a, v) = { Raw = a + v.Raw }

let a = { Raw = 2 }
let b = a + 3           // ok
let c = 3 + a           // ok
let d = { Raw = obj() } // No problemo
```

Too far off? Try this:

```
type Value<'T> =
    val Raw : 'T
    new (raw) = { Raw = raw }
    static member inline (+) (v : Value<_>, w : Value<_>) = Value(v.Raw + w.Raw)
    static member inline (+) (v : Value<_>, a)            = Value(v.Raw + a)
    static member inline (+) (a, v : Value<_>)            = Value(a + v.Raw)

let a = Value(2)
let b = a + 3      // OK
let c = 3 + a      // OK
let d = Value(obj) // No problemo
```

Not sure what is going on here, but it's not very consistent.