# F# operator overloading riddle 2

Tags: f#

In F# operator overloading seems powerful but also tricky to get right.
I have following class:

```
 type Value<'T> = 
    with
        static member inline  (+) (a : Value<'U>, b: Value<'U>) : Value<'U> = 
           do stuff
```

If i define another overload for + with :

```
static member inline  (+) (a : Value<'U>, b: 'U) : Value<'U> = 
           do stuff
```

It works. But if i want a symmetric operator:

```
static member inline  (+) (b: 'U, a : Value<'U>) : Value<'U> = 
           do stuff
```

The compiler complains:

```
let a = Value<int>(2);
let b = a + 3 // ok
let c = 3 + a //<-- error here
```

**Error 3 Type inference problem too complicated (maximum iteration depth reached). Consider adding further type annotations**

Is there a way around this and stay generic?

I am using F# 3.1

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Removing the type annotations will solve the issue you pointed out, but you didn't notice there is another issue: try invoking the first overload, the compiler will not know which overload to call. It's a shame the overload resolution doesn't pick up the right one.

One tricky way to get everything working at compile time is to declare only the first overload into the type, and for the rest use the trick of redefining the `(+)` operator using an intermediate type:

```
type Value<'T> = Value of 'T with
    static member inline  (+) (Value a, Value b) = Value (a + b)

type Sum = Sum with
    static member inline (?<-) (Sum, a, b) = a + b
    static member inline (?<-) (Sum, Value a, b) = Value (a + b)
    static member inline (?<-) (Sum, b, Value a) = Value (a + b)

let inline (+) a b :'t = (?<-) Sum a b

// test
let v = Value(2)
let a = v + v
let b = v + 3
let c = 3 + v
let d = Value(Value 7) + Value(Value 10)
let e = 5 + 7
```

**UPDATE**

I've found another workaround which I prefer since it does not require redefining the (+) operator, the trick is to create a base class and move some overloads there:

```
type BaseValue<'T>(v : 'T) =
    member x.V = v

type Value<'T>(v : 'T) =
    inherit BaseValue<'T>(v : 'T)
    static member inline  (+) (a : Value<_>, b: Value<_>) = Value(b.V+a.V)

type BaseValue with
    static member inline  (+) (a: BaseValue<_>, b) = Value(b+a.V)
    static member inline  (+) (b, a: BaseValue<_>) = Value(b+a.V)


// test
let v = Value(2)
let a = v + v
let b = v + 3
let c = 3 + v
let d = Value(Value 7) + Value(Value 10)
let e = 5 + 7
```

Comment: Hi Gustavo, thanks for this trick. I think this is the only workaround. will this trick work if I have more types like Value<'T>?

Comment: Things I did not know: A) you can define ternary operators. this is a hack. B) Even though ?<- is ternary with record param, if I call it (?<-)(sum,a,b) it does not compile...

Comment: Yes, it may work with more types but it's not straight forward. You can't define ternary operators other than (?<-), the way to call it is either (?<-) a b c or a ? (b) <- c there is no tupled call.

Comment: @Gustavo - I think you no longer need to use an operator; you can use named methods with more than 2 types in the `(^a or ^b or ...)` part of the static member constraint.  This requires an explicit annotation but seems significantly less hacky.

Comment: @kvb Yes, you are correct as from F# 3.0 I can use a method with constraints too. Both solutions seems a bit hacky to me, ideally overload resolution would resolve to the method that matches the best.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in the fact that there is no way to resolve between the first and, say, the second overload when the second parameter to the second overload is a `Value<'T>` itself.

Here is a complete version that causes the error:

```
type Value<'T>(v : 'T) =
    member x.V = v
    with
        static member inline  (+) (a : Value<'U>, b: Value<'U>) : Value<'U> = 
            Value<'U>(b.V+a.V)

        static member inline  (+) (a : Value<'U>, b: 'U) : Value<'U> = 
            Value<'U>(b+a.V)

        static member inline  (+) (b: 'U, a : Value<'U>) : Value<'U> = 
            Value<'U>(b+a.V)


let a = Value<int>(2);
let b = a + 3
let c = 3 + a
```

I'd say write one operator overload, and do pattern matching on type inside it? Ugly, I know.